# How can I get the free out IPs in our IDC?

Tags: linux

Our company have a IDC (Internet Data Center), and in our IDC, there are many host machines, every host has 1-3 IPs.

There is a situation, such as one host machine has 3 IPs(eg. `102.23.33.1` -> `102.23.33.3`). (means in the host machine, have configured the IPs to it)

If the host machine only use `102.23.33.1`, and there free out the `102.23.33.2` and `102.23.33.3`. We want to find out the free IPs.

How can I do that? I tried to use the forloop to ping the whole IPs, but this is not accurate, because some host machine are baned  for `ping`.

---

**EDIT**

I means the host machine if has 3 IPs, and all can ping them, but the host machine only use the first IP to connect with public network, how can I find the other 2 IPs host machine do not use (or do not often use)?

---

**EDIT-2**

I mean the IPs all configured on the OS but may not be actually using them.

---

**EDIT - 3**

So, all the before, there can be understood as bellow:

I have a Router, and under it, there are many host machines, and every host machine have some IPs, and how can I record the IPs that go through the Router everyday.

Is there a tool for record the IPs which get through the Router? Or how can I realize my requirement ?

Comment: [There are 93 possible meanings for IDC.](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/IDC)

Comment: You'll need to be more clear.  Do you mean, the machines have IP addresses allocated on paper, but may not have them configured at the OS level, or that they're all configured on the OS but may not be actually using them?

Comment: @EightBitTony The later.

Comment: Then there's no easy answer - you need to analyse the traffic on each interface on each host, either at the host end or at the switch end (assuming they're real switches), or find some other network traffic management tool which will show you (`iptables`?)

Comment: Or do you mean that you *know* the other two IP addresses are free?  In which case, you need to (automate) logging on to each server and getting the network config.

Comment: No, I don't know the IPs if is free. So, I am thinking if there is a method(tool) we can use on Router.

Comment: What model / device is the router?  Are there 10 hosts, or 100, or 10,000 hosts (it matters).

Answer (score 1):

This adds a logging rule into the iptables FORWARD chain:

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix 'MYIPS: '
```

This searches for the matching packets:

```
# grep MYIPS /var/log/syslog
```

The file name may depend on your Linux distribution.

And this generates a list of unique IP addresses seen by the forwarding chain in your router:

```
# grep -oE '(SRC|DST)=[0-9.]*' /var/log/syslog | sed 's/.*=//' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear. Your router is a Linux machine? or a networking device?
You may check the dhcp lease list on your dhcp server if you are using a DHCP to assign the IP addresses. that will help you better.

Comment: The IPs is manual configuration.