# Is there a tool for record the IPs which get through the Router?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a Router, and under it, there are many host machines, and every host machine have some IPs, and how can I record the IPs that go through the Router everyday.

Is there a tool for record the IPs which get through the Router? Or how can I realize my requirement ?

Comment: Please only ask one question - your other question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398567/how-can-i-get-the-free-out-ips-in-our-idc) doesn't have an answer yet.  I suggest you refine that question, with a full description of the issue, rather than asking another question.